# MPDF won't accept some characters

Tags: html, codeigniter, pdf, utf-8, mpdf

MPDF will not print to PDF if it encounters a character like this one `<` (lower than).

I tried configuring MPDF like this:

```
$this->ignore_invalid_utf8 = true;
```

and

```
$this->allow_charset_conversion = false;
```

But with no success.

The text I'm trying to print looks like this:

```
test<text
```

If I remove the `<` char from text, everything goes well.

Any ideas on how to make MPDF print those chars?

i have updated the mpdf library to MPDF57

and with text<>text it works

but with only `text < text` its not working

Comment: Have you tried it like this ? ```&lt;```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should update your mpdf library because i am also using mpdf and it works with those character for me, you can see this in image.Update your library and try again[image: sample pdf with "<>" character]